# Are #define-s in a source file local to that object?

Tags: c

I'm unsure of the terminology, but I would like to know if in the following scenario, `main.c` has access to `x.c`s `#define`s:

```
/*x.h*/
#define ONE 1
```

```
/*x.c*/
#include "x.h"
#define TWO 2
```

```
/*main.c*/
#include "x.h"
int a = ONE;
int b = TWO;
```

You could just tell me to run `gcc -o out main.c x.c` if I want to know. But it might work, yet not be correct. This is why I am asking you. My goal is to have the `#define`s in `x.c` be local to that file, so they don't clash with any others in `main.c`. On the other hand, I do want `#define`s from `x.h` to be available to `main.c` because they need to be used when implementing the functions from `x.c`

Please advise

Comment: If you `#define` *after* all the `#include` directives: yes. If you `#define` *before* any `#include` file it will be considered by it.

Comment: main.c does not contain the preprocessor directives (`#define`s are just one of many) written in other compilation units (.c files + their preprocessor directives once expanded).

Comment: For example with MSVC you must `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before you `#include <math.h>` to make macros such as `M_PI` available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two .c files are equivalent to the following:
x.c :

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
```

main.c :

```
#define ONE 1
int a = ONE;
int b = TWO;
```

Any `#define` in a .c file will be local to that file. This is a common practice when optimizing code, leave a `#define` that is exclusively used in a .c file declared in that same c file.

Edit : BUT as `#defines` and `#includes` (and many other preprocessor directives) are expanded, this is done from top to bottom. meaning that one directive can then recieve `#define`s from some `#include` that was expanded earlier.
Here's an example of what I'm saying:
a.h :

```
#define A 1
```

b.h :

```
#define NEW_A A+1
```

main.c :

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%i, %i\n", A, NEW_A);
    return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
1, 2
```

I'd suggest reading about compilation units and preprocessor directives in C.

Comment: Even more important, the bodies of `#defines` are not expanded when the `#define` occurs, they are expanded when it is used.  So even if you swap the order of the `#include`s (and define `NEW_A` first), you'll get the same result.